# How to lookup configured Struts action

Tags: java, servlets, struts-1

I want to do the following:

```
final Action myAction = getActionDefinedInStrutsConfig(param);
myAction.execute(params);
```

Is there a way to lookup the actions that the `ActionServlet` has initialized ?

I can create a new one like so:

```
 final Action myAction = new ActionImpl();
 myAction.execute(params);
```

but this way the new action is not properly initialized, the attached servlet is not set and [getServlet()](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/api/org/apache/struts/action/ActionForm.html#getServlet%28%29) returns null.

---

A little clarification on why I need this:

The problem is that I currently have 2 login pages. One for normal users and one for admins. They should be separate systems completely, but the fact is they're currently not. I need to make a 'proxy' login page which decides which login page to redirect to according to the request. If I redirect to the URL however the UI would be drawn. I need to call the either the user or admin login actions to process my proxy page request. Also moving the logic inside a service, while being the correct approach, is not currently an option.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly and for what purpose exactly?

Comment: Call another action from my action. Because I want to call its logic without drawing its UI.

Comment: You can forward your action to another action in `struts-config.xml`

Comment: Wouldn't this always draw the UI of the action I'm forwarding to ? In my tests I can't seem to make it not draw the UI. I want to make the called action process my request, without drawing its own UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since I see what you mean here's what I would suggest:

- Use your action for validatory purposes, i.e., retrieval of data from `ActionForm` and checking for validity. Once all information is done, send the info to a service.
- The service (need not to be a web service, but a simple POJO) will have the business logic of the application, with relevant exceptions and return types. Once you call the relevant service with its method, retrieve the result and, finally,
- Populate your necessary `ActionForm` or do a `mapping.findForward()`.

This way, if you need another business logic that is used by another Struts Action, rather call the service that the 2nd action uses. This is an effective way for code-reuse and good OOP practise.

Hope this helps.

---

The hackable way would be to do this:

```
final Action myAction = new ActionImpl();
myAction.setServlet(getServlet());
/* ONLY if your form enctype is "multipart/request-data". */
myAction.setMultipartRequestHandler(getMultipartRequestHandler());

//Finally
myAction.execute(params);
```

Comment: This is the standart way to do it yes. In a legacy system however I want to do this at controller level. Not on business service level (where the logic is), the way you suggest is the right way. I can explain why I need it on controller level if you want, but I don't want to waste your time.

Comment: Go ahead Simeon, We have no idea how your system is setup and I wouldn't suggest changing the controller level of things.....

Comment: The problem is that I currently have 2 login pages. One for normal users and 1 for admins. They should be separate systems completely, but the fact is they're currently not. I need to make a 'proxy' login page which decides which login page to redirect to according to the request. If I redirect to the URL however the UI would be drawn. I need to call the either the user or admin login actions to process my proxy page request. Also moving the logic inside a service, while being the correct approach, is not currently an option.

Comment: Then add another parameter that you can retrieve through a request and add a proxy to forward such request.

Answer (score 0):

You can define actions in your forwards:

```
    <action parameter="command" path="/firstAction"
        input="firstAction.tiles" name="someForm" scope="session" validate="true" type="com.mycompany.FirstAction">
        <forward name="toSecond" path="/secondAction.do?command=someMethod" redirect="true"/>
    </action>

    <action parameter="command" path="/secondAction" input="secondAction.tiles" name="someForm"
        scope="session" validate="true" type="com.mycompany.SecondAction">
        <forward name="backToFirst" path="/firstAction.do?command=myMethod" redirect="true" />
    </action>
```

Now you can use `mapping.findForward("toSecond")`, in your first action and `mapping.findForward("backToFirst")` on the other.

Comment: This doesn't work for me as I don't want to draw the UI of the action I'm forwarding to. Is there a way to forward without drawing the UI of the action you're forwarding to ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are looking to reuse the code, right? Can't you process the request in the second action and forward it to the first action? You could also have both actions inherit from a class with a `doStuff(Request req)`.